# cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Tests'

Tags: powershell

cannot convert value to type System.String : ParameterArgumentTransformationError

```
Param(
    # Use this flag to attach a debugger
    [switch]$AttachDebugger,

    # Use this flag to run the test outside of razzle window (in which case, all required file should be in the same dir)
    [switch]$NoRazzle,

    # Optional test specifier.
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]$Tests,

    # Optional category
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]$Category
)

$command = "Run-Tests.ps1"
$arguments = @("-Type", "Group")
if($AttachDebugger)
{
    $arguments += ("-AttachDebugger")
}
if($NoRazzle)
{
    $arguments += ("-NoRazzle")
}
if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($Category))
{
    $arguments += ("-Category", "$Category")
}
if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($Tests))
{
    $arguments += ("-Tests", "$Tests")
}
& "$PSScriptRoot\Run-Tests" $arguments
```

$Tests in Run-Tests is of datatype string. How to tackle this?

Comment: How do you run this script?

Comment: Run-GroupTests.ps1 -Category <string> -Tests <string>

Comment: I wasn't able to replicate, everything worked fine for me.

Comment: @IshuGoyal I meant as in, from where? `powershell.exe`? A scheduled task? A .bat file? And what do you supply as the argument after `-Tests`?

Comment: I think the call operator & is expecting a string as the arguments parameter but you are providing a hashtable.

Comment: Could you please hardcode the arguments and see ? It seems that it is trying to convert a map into string